# Number of comparisons in .net 4.5 sort

Tags: c#, sorting, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I do know that the sort algorithm of 4.5 is changed from 4.0, but I suspect that something is wrong to the implementation of introspective sort.
It seems in the case of a reverse sorted list behaves erratically, when someones expect the same number of comparisons with the "sorted" case (as is in 4.0), that number is strangely very big.

.net 4 x64

random 25514058, sorted 20525265, reversed 20525285

.net 4.5 x64

random 22112103, sorted 16935357, reversed **31148728** !!

The code I used to get the number of comparisons (compiled using 4.0 and 4.5) is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace sortTest {
class Program {
    class CmpCount : IComparer<int> {
        private int _count;
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public int Count {
            get {
                return _count;
            }
        }



        public int Compare( int x, int y ) {
            _count++;
            return x.CompareTo( y );
        }
    }
    static void Main( string[] args ) {
        Random rnd = new Random(1234);
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ ) {
            list.Add( rnd.Next() );
        }
        CmpCount cmp = new CmpCount();
        list.Sort( cmp );
        int random = cmp.Count;

        cmp = new CmpCount();
        list.Sort( cmp );
        int sorted = cmp.Count;

        cmp = new CmpCount();
        list.Reverse();
        list.Sort( cmp );
        int reversed = cmp.Count;

        Console.WriteLine("random {0}, sorted {1}, reversed {2}",random,sorted,reversed);
    }
}
}
```

**Edit**: I am debugging the source code and it seems that HeapSort is never called. Perhaps it needs a special crafted input, that will trigger it. So actually in the above cases, 4.5 sort is actually doing just a quicksort.

Quick looking in the source it seems that the 4.0 quicksort is more sophisticated while 4.5 is a poor (straight from books?) implementation.

If I understand correctly, also the 4.5 seems to blindly favor already sorted lists. That's perhaps the issue with the reversed sorted list

Answer (score 2):

The .NET 4.5 implementation of introsort begins by trying to do a Quicksort. When it sees the recursion depth go beyond a particular point, it stops the Quicksort and starts over with a Heap sort.

So it's not unreasonable to expect a larger number of comparisons because the algorithm is doing a partial sort and then restarting to do a full sort.

Also, there's no telling how the .NET Quicksort is picking the items to do its partitioning. Likely it's using median of 3. But is it picking a random three? First, middle, and last? The partitioning could be different (and thus the number of comparisons could be different) for two sorts of the same array.

In any case, Introsort doesn't claim to be perfect. It's quite possible that the algorithm will detect a potential worst case and switch to Heap sort even though using quicksort would have been faster. Introsort avoids worst case behavior, but sometimes can exhibit non-optimal behavior.

In addition, there's no guarantee that the arrays you're sorting are the same. Are you sure that the `Random` class implementation didn't change between .NET 4 and .NET 4.5? It's possible that `Random(1234)` creates a different sequence on 4.5 than it did on 4.0. If that's so, you're not comparing sorts on the same array.

Comment: We could check if heap sort is being triggered by trying a smaller input array. After that, if we conclude that it _is_ hitting the heap sort then it seems like the only reason would be what you suggested which is that the way they are picking the pivot isn't the original `median(first, middle, last)` but something else (possibly just random?). Relatedly, I think your comment on `Random` is also spot on but for a different reason. OP doesn't claim that the two arrays are the same in 4.0 and 4.5 (in fact... they're supposed to be "random") but sample size seems to be missing from OP.

Comment: @roliu: He is initializing the rng with a seed: `rnd = Random(1234)`, so he's going to get the same sequence each time he runs it on .NET 4. And every .NET 4.5 run will get the same sequence. Whether those two sequences are the same is an open question. Sample size is `1000000`: that's how many items he adds to the list.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the seed. For sample size I meant the number of lists. It may be possible that the particular random list he generated, when reversed, works well with quicksort but not introsort.